# Why does mouse button 2 and 3 behave differently for menu?

Tags: windows, tcl, tk-toolkit

I wanted to map both mouse button 2 and 3 to the same command for doing the same thing, but the behaviour is not the same. Here is the full Tcl code snippet for reproducing the behavior:

```
package require Tk

menu .menu

foreach button {<2> <3>} {
  bind . $button {.menu post %X %Y}
}
```

Both buttons 2 and 3 post the menu as expected while not currently posted. The weird part is that while posted, pressing button 3 will re-post the menu on the new location, whereas pressing button 2 has no apparent effect. After un-posting by pressing Esc pressing 2 will post the menu at location, so clearly button 2 is properly associated with the command. Pressing button 3 while menu is open by a press on button 2 correctly posts the menu at the new location.

Why does it behave this way?

Windows 10, ActiveTcl 8.6.7 Build 0 (64-bit).

Comment: Must be windows eating the button #2 event in its menu implementation (Tk uses native menus on windows). On linux it works the same with both buttons.

Comment: I hope it's something simple like that. I don't want to dive into the murky depths of the event processing engine again for at least a few months more; it's got some seriously brain-bending details under the covers…